# Inserting rows into a table from another table without iterating over a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, cursor

I have the below tables, Robot and RobotTestResult. I want to migrate the DateTested field in Robot to the DateTested field in RobotTestResult for the corresponding Robot.

```
Robot         RobotTestResult
--------      ---------------
RobotID       RobotTestID (Identity)
DateTested    RobotID
              DateTested
```

There will be at most 1 entry in the RobotTestResult table for any Robot

Some Robots will have a corresponding entry in the RobotTestResult table, I can update those values with a simple join:

```
UPDATE RTR
SET RTR.DateTested = r.DateTested
FROM [dbo].[RobotTestResult] RTR
JOIN [Robot] r
ON RTR.RobotID = r.RobotID;
```

The problem is with Robots who do not have an entry in the RobotTestResult table. The only way I can think of is to use a Cursor to iterate through each Robot that does not have an RTR entry and do an insert, but I feel like there must be a more efficient way.

Edit to add:  If no DateTested value exists in Robot, no RobotTestResult should be inserted.

Comment: So you want to add a new `RobotTestResult` record for every Robot that doesn't already have one?

Comment: A new RobotTestResult for every Robot with a DateTested value only. If no DateTested value exists in Robot, no action should be taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer using `NOT EXISTS` for this scenario as it matches the logic of the problem.

```
INSERT INTO RobotTestResults (RobotID, DatedTest)
    SELECT RobotID, DateTest
    FROM Robot R
    WHERE DateTest IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM RobotTestRules RTR
        WHERE RTR.RobotID = R.RobotID
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve the same using MERGE statement also. I personally like @Dale K solution. But, adding this as an additional option in TSQL.

```sql
MERGE [dbo].[RobotTestResult] as tgt
USING (SELECT * FROM Robot) AS src
ON tgt.RobotID = src.RobotID AND src.DateTested IS NOT NULL
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET DateTested = src.DateTested
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (RobotID, DateTested)
VALUES (src.RobotID, src.DateTested);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution.   Basically, if the left join doesn't find a match, then add the value into RobotTestResults

```
INSERT INTO RobotTestResults
(RobotID,DatedTest)
SELECT RobotID,DateTest
FROM Robot r
LEFT JOIN RobotTestRules rtr on rtr.robotID = r.robitID
WHERE rtr.robotID is NULL
```